# Trying to Create a Sprite Wall

Tags: android, android-canvas, surfaceview

I am trying to develop a Android Game using Canvas and `Animation` Sprites in a `SurfaceView`. I didn't have any issues creating the Animations but my problem is now that i would like to implement a Wall. Maybe somebody has a hint for me which direction to take...

Comment: What do you mean by "implement a Wall" ?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: With a Wall i mean some kind of barrier(s), where my Sprite bounces off. I haven really tried much so far because i really don know how to do this...

Comment: Google for "game collision detection". You can find source for a complete Breakout game in https://github.com/fadden/android-breakout . http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ may be a better place to ask questions.